# Error: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate

I am trying to get Spring and Hibernate working without a persistence.xml. I am setting up my entities package scanner on my context.xml file, like this:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernatePropertiesConfigurer"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.therubythree.simpleapi.entities"/>
</bean>
```

What am I missing?

I keep getting the error:

```
No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, packagesToScan should work.

Ex -

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="tutorials.core.models.entities"></property>
```

If it doesn't then you can try something like this. (according docs, this is the default path)

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
    ...
</bean>
```

After that you should add the persistence.xml in the META-INF( under src/main/resources)

Ex -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="studentPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
<class>tutorials.models.entities.Student</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: There is no property persistenceXmlLocation. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @CuriousMind yes there is, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPersistenceXmlLocation-java.lang.String-